# Phonon eigenfrequencies under time reversal

Tags: classical-mechanics, vibrations, time-reversal-symmetry, phonons

In G. P. Srivastava's "The Physics of Phonons", 1e., the ansatz which solves Newton's second law in the harmonic approximation is taken to be

$$
u_\alpha(\ell b;t)
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m_b}}\sum_q \varepsilon_\alpha(b;qs)\,\exp[i(q\cdot\ell -\omega_{qs}t)]
$$

where $\ell,b,q,s$ denote, respectively, the coordinates of the $\ell$th unit cell, the coordinates of the $b$th basis atom, the phonon wavevector $q$, and the branches $s$ of the dispersion relation. The $\{\varepsilon_\alpha(b;qs)\}$ are components of the vibrational eigenvectors which diagonalize the (Hermitian) dynamical matrix:

$$
\omega_{qs}^2\,\varepsilon_\alpha(b;qs)=\sum_{b'\alpha'}D_{\alpha\alpha'}(bb';q)\,\varepsilon_{\alpha'}(b';qs)
$$

Srivistava claims "from time reversal symmetry it follows that"

$$
\omega_{-qs}^2=\omega_{qs}^2
$$

I am not sure how to prove this. I tried mapping  $t\rightarrow-t,~q\rightarrow-q$ in the ansatz and demanding the result be equal to $u_\alpha(\ell b;t)$ itself, but that did not seem to lead anywhere. If someone could provide a hint re. how to proceed, that would be much appreciated. Thank you!